# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$pasta' (T_VARIABLE) in

Tags: php

Pessoal eu estou tendo esse erro, li que essa mensagem aparece quando ocorre um erro em uma linha anterior do código, o que e estranho pra  mim é que está acontecendo na primeira linha do arquivo.

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$pasta' (T_VARIABLE) in**

```
<?php
 $pasta = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/arquivos/";

 if(is_dir($pasta))
 {
  $diretorio = dir($pasta);

  while($arquivo = $diretorio->read())
  {
   if(($arquivo != '.') && ($arquivo != '..'))
   {
    unlink($pasta.$arquivo);
    echo 'Arquivo '.$arquivo.' foi apagado com sucesso. <br />';
   }
  }

  $diretorio->close();
 }
 else
 {
  echo 'A pasta não existe.';
 }
?>
```

Comment: Como você executou este arquivo?

Comment: Rapaz, copiei seu codigo daqui e apresentou o mesmo erro, porém quando reescrevi, exatamente igual, funcionou

Comment: pois é, é exatamente o que o outro companheiro falou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Os seus espaços não são espaços e nem tabs, o que esta dentro disto a seguir (do quadro cinza abaixo):

- 

Veja:

- O valor ASCII de espaço (" ") é `32`
- O valor ASCII de tab ("\t") é `9`
- Já o valor ASCII desse caractere que você usou como espaço é `8195`

Ou seja, apesar de parecer espaço ele não é.

É outro caractere, mas não é nem espaço e nem tabulação, com certeza você esta usando um editor de texto que não serve para escrever códigos, provavelmente esta usando *Microsoft Word* ou *WordPad* ou o *TextEdit* do Mac OSX em modo "documento avançado"

Assim o PHP não vai funcionar e nenhum outro tipo script provavelmente, então recomendo que **reescreva manualmente** o seu código usando um editor de texto apropriado, como um destes:

- SublimeText: https://www.sublimetext.com
- Notepad++: https://notepad-plus-plus.org
- https://code.visualstudio.com

Comment: não sabia que isso ocorria usando editores não específico para códigos, já me deparei com problemas assim em que o código, após reescrito em um editor, funcionava, obrigado pela informação.

Comment: @WeesSmith editores chamados richtext usam esquemas proprios, tipo MSWord, Wordpad, etc. Isso porque eles não são só texto, são codificações proprias

Comment: Entendi, aqui mesmo no Stack já vi problemas similares ao dele, agr sei um motivo possivel.

Comment: cara eu vou reescrever, faz sentido o que falou mas o estranho é que eu ele esta no sublime eu não sei porque de ter acontecido mas vou reescrever manualmente

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: por nada caro @MarcosGoulartdeOliveira essa sua duvida é muito interessante para a comunidade, fazia tempo que queria falar deste tipo de problema. Assim que reescrever com um dos programas que citei por favor comenta aqui se funcionou, eu ficaria muito grato com o seu feedback ;)

Comment: Opa, desculpa a demora pra responder sou novo programando e como usuário no stack, antes eu só entrava pra ver respostas nunca tinha respondido ou perguntado antes. Mas funcionou sim. Mas não foi exatamente como tu falou eu estava usando o sublime mas eu copiei grande parte do código de um site quando eu reescrevi ele funcionou mas desde o começo estava no sublime,

Comment: @MarcosGoulartdeOliveira provavelmente o autor do tal site formatou a postagem pelo word ou outro programa assim e na hora de copiar pro site dele ficou com este aparentes espaços, ai por isto você acabou pagando o preço hehehe, então a documentação do https://php.net tem muitos exemplos prontos, convém copiar de lá, exemplo: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.dir.php e modificar a sua necessidade :)

Answer (score 1):

Simplesmente reescrevi o código e funcionou:

```
if(is_dir($pasta)){
    $diretorio = dir($pasta);
    while($arquivo=$diretorio->read()){
        if(($arquivo!='.')&&($arquivo!='..')){
            unlink($pasta.$arquivo);
            echo "Arquivo $arquivo foi apagado com sucesso.<br>";
        }
    }
    $diretorio->close();
}else{
    echo "A pasta não existe";
}
```

Acredito que seja exatamente o que o @GuilhermeNascimento disse agora na resposta dele.